# choices field populate error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following field in one of my model(Person) .

```
field1 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Field",choices=populate_games(), max_length=50)
```

populate_games has been added to utils module. Here is the code for that

```
def populate_games():
    from cloudwork.work.models import Game
    return Game.objects.values_list('name', 'name').distinct('name')
```

It works great in both production and development. But when in production it throws an error saying Person can't be imported in one of the class that is importing Person class and points to the code posted above.

I tried replacing populate_games() with different options to check if that was generating errors. 
Here are the list I replaced populate_games() with

```
Game.objects.values_list('name', 'name').distinct('name')
```

I created a class method in Game class to call Game.populate_games() ....

noting seems to resolve the error.

Comment: You're going to have to show us the code for `populate_games()`.

Comment: @Joe added the code for populate_games() above.

Comment: What's `cloudwork.work.models`? Is it external? Does it have dependencies which need to be installed?

Comment: cloudwork is my project. work is one of the app . Games model is in work app. that is why I am importing cloudwork.work.models so that I can use Game.objects.values_list('name', 'name').distinct('name').

Answer (score 1):

With high probability you have circular imports here. Try this

```
from django.db.models import get_model

def populate_games():
    Game = get_model('work', 'Game') # I assume 'work' is the name of the app
    return Game.objects.values_list('name', 'name').distinct('name')
```

Comment: I didn't realize we couldn't circular import. Seems like I have circular import elsewhere as well :(. But , it works great. Its only that I get email notifications .